# Inserting new org roam node fails

Tags: config, org-roam

I recently moved my Org Roam directory to a new machine. However, creating new nodes with `org-roam-node-find` fails with the error message `run-hooks: Symbol’s function definition is void: org-tempo-setup`. I tried running `org-roam-db-clear-all` and then `org-roam-db-sync` but it doesn't fix the issue.

Browsing and reading existing nodes works fine though.

Here is my config for Org-Roam:

```
;; Org roam setup
(use-package org-roam :ensure t)
(setq org-roam-directory "~/Desktop/secbrain")

(org-roam-setup)
```

Why am I seeing this error message?

Comment: Add `(require 'org-tempo)` to your init file.

Comment: Thank you. So the `org-tempo` error is gone but now I get this error `run-hooks: Symbol’s value as variable is void: org-mouse-features`

Comment: Add `(require 'org-mouse)` to your init file.

Comment: This solved the problem. Do you know why I have to add these things manually?

Comment: Presumably, you had them on the old machine: you probably installed them when you set up the hook that is now complaining,  then you forgot about it. Both of these packages are optional, so you have to add them to your emacs session if you want to use them - just like any other library that is not set up for autoloading. Correction: actually `org-mouse` seems to be automatically loaded even if I start with `emacs -Q` so if your version were recent enough, you probably would not need to require it any more.